# URLConnection and POST method android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am trying to make a post request using the reference of [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) documentation. But the problem is that the PHP developer at the other end is not able to receive the value of the parameter hence is not able to send a proper response. Am I missing something out here.

// Edits ;

I am making a HTTP Post request. As you can seen the code below. I am writing the arguments and parameters (location_id=3) to the outputstream. I have also pasted the code for PHP which i have been using. Now the problem is:

The parameter value ( which is 3 ) is not received at the PHP code so I am getting a response which is surrounded by the else block. So I just want to know if there is an error in the android code or the PHP code

@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

```
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG,Constants.FETCH_ALL_THEMES_ASYNC_TASK);
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG," The url to be fetched "+params[0]);

        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

//                 /* optional request header */
//            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
//
//                /* optional request header */
//            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                /* for Get request */
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location_id",params[1]));

            outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
            bufferedWriter.write(writeToOutputStream(nameValuePairs));


            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, " The response is " + response);



                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                if(inputStream != null){

                    inputStream.close();
                }
                if(outputStream != null){
                    outputStream.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return false;

    }
```

// Here is the code for writeToOutputStream

```
public String writeToOutputStream(List<BasicNameValuePair> keyValuePair)throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

    String result="";
    boolean firstTime = true;

    for(BasicNameValuePair pair : keyValuePair){


        if(firstTime){

            firstTime = false;
        }
        else{

            result = result.concat("&");

        }

        result = result + URLEncoder.encode(pair.getKey(), "UTF-8");
        result = result + "=";
        result =  result+ URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(),"UTF-8");

    }

    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG," The result is "+result);
    return result;

}
```

// Here is the code for convertInputStream to String

```
public String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {

        String line="";
        String result="";
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG," The line value is "+line);
            result += line;

        }

            /* Close Stream */
        if(null!=inputStream){
            inputStream.close();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Here is the PHP CODE

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    header ('Content-Type:application/json');

    if(isset($_POST['location_id']))
    {
        $id=$_POST['location_id'];

        $selectThemeQuery = mysql_query("select theme_id from location_theme where location_id='$id'",$conn) or die (mysql_error());
        $noRows = mysql_num_rows($selectThemeQuery);
         //echo "HI";
        if($noRows > 0)
        { 
            $result = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectThemeQuery))
            {
                $themeid = $row['theme_id'];
                //echo "HI";
                $selectNameQuery = mysql_query("select theme_name,theme_image from theme where theme_id='$themeid'",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
                $numRows = mysql_num_rows($selectNameQuery);

                if($numRows > 0)
                {
                    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectNameQuery))
                    {
                        $name = $rows['theme_name'];
                        $image = $rows['theme_image'];

                        $result[] = array('theme_id'=>$themeid,'theme_name'=>$name, 'theme_image'=>$image);
                    }

                }

            }
            //echo json_encode($result);
                        echo json_encode("Hi");
        }
        else
        {
                $data2[] = array('Notice'=>false);
                echo json_encode($data2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Not Proper Data";
    }


?>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: Have you considered using something that can do 95% of the whole stuff for you? For example, POST + JSON sounds like "REST Service", for which Spring-Web offers some great tools (but there are probably dozens of other libraries for that out there)

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz : Can you please elaborate a bit and I hope you are answering a solution for android.

Comment: `the PHP developer at the other end is not able to receive the value of the parameter`. Well start telling how he wants to receive which parameter. Otherwise we have to gues, You could post your php script.

Comment: Where are you sending JSON? There is nothing in your code that contains JSON. Show better what you or doing or explain.

Comment: Please edit your post so all functions are decent in a code block. Don't make such a mess.

Comment: @greenapps : Hey the PHP code has been uploaded. I am just making a HTTP Post request to the link with the parameter location_id, which is written to the output stream as per the tutorial.I hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: 'The PHP developer at the other end is not able to receive the value of the parameter hence is not able to send a proper response'. What do you mean by that ? What is the response you get? 'echo $_POST['location_id'];'. Well what does it echo?  'if(isset($_POST['location_id']))'. Well is it set? You should give more to the point information.

Comment: Please remove 'Parsing JSON' from the subject of your post. There is no json parsing involved in your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

You use a buffered writer so it can only buffer instead of write.
To force all been written:

```
bufferedWriter.write(writeToOutputStream(nameValuePairs));        
bufferedWriter.flush();
```

And then ask for a response code. And don't call a response code a status code.

`writeToOutputStream()` ??? What a terrible name. That function does not write to an output stream. It justs makes a text string.

Comment: Yup that worked but why did we remove setChunkedStreamingMode(0) . Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, I would suggest using a library like [Spring-Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android).

Spring-Android contains a [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/2.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) class, which is a quite effective REST-Client. For example, a simple POST request would be...

```
myRestTemplate.exchange("http://www.example.net", HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity( ...some JSON string ...), String.class );
```

To create the JSON String, I suggest a library like Jackson, which should work fine on Android, see for example [here](https://dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android). Not sure if Jackson integrates as fine in Spring-Android as it does in Spring-Web, but in any case, using it to create the Json Strings manually should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

for post method
create a string builder first

```
StringBuilder strbul=new StringBuilder();
```

then append the data like

```
strbul.append("name=sangeet&state=kerala");
```

then write to output stream like

```
httpurlconnection.getOutput().write(strbul.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

php script will recieve that data on

```
$_POST['name'] and $_POST['state']
```

Comment: I dont see that helping as I am already using concat. But still tried to ensure the result didnt return.Thanx